# How do I configure IIS to prevent click jacking and pass a DAST scan?

Tags: iis

[image: IIS SETTINGS]

My application is failing a DAST scan and the issue is "CSP frame-ancestors missing". These are the current settings for headers in IIS, so does anyone have a suggestion about which could be incorrect or if more need to be added?

Comment: You have add enough response headers, no need to add other headers. Just add it at site level or server level.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a single content-security-header, with ";" between different sections as below

Content-Security-Policy: img-src 'none';frame-ancestors 'none';